# dpkg -l still shows new version of file

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I ran the command `dpkg -l` before I removed two updates from Debian 8.11.  I then did `sudo apt-get remove openssl`  and `sudo apt-get remove --purge wget` and rebooted the device.  When I did `dpkg -l` it showed me the exact same version as before I removed it. The only way I could tell it was removed was by running the `sudo apt-get remove` command again. Of course, when I reinstalled the update it did install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove a package, `dpkg -l` will still show it if it still knows about it. To determine the package’s status, you need to look at the first column: this will show `ii` for installed packages, `rc` for removed packages which are still configured, `un` for non-installed packages, and various other values summarised in the first two lines of `dpkg -l`’s output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
```

So unless `dpkg -l` showed `ii` for both removed packages, the behaviour you saw is normal.

Comment: ahhh so I only removed the package I did not actually uninstall it.  I guess I need to find out how to do that.

Comment: I recommend taking the time to read the Debian documentation; see [this section](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_the_event_flow_of_the_package_management) of the Reference in this particular case.